# AngularJS - How to make select element have an empty option selected by default?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a `<select>` element which is filled by angular, and the options are properly displayed with the data in `ctrl.servicios` :

```
<select id="id_select_token" ng-model="ctrl.token" class="form-control input-sm"
                      ng-selected="ctrl.token == item.Clv_Servicio" 
                      ng-change="ctrl.GetPrecioToken();"
                      ng-options="item as item.Descripcion for item in ctrl.servicios track by item.Clv_Servicio">
                      <option value="">Selecciona</option>
                    </select>
```

The issue is, I want this select to, by default, have the `<option value="">Selecciona</option>` selected. I've tried to add `selected="selected"` to that option, but it doesn't work. I also tried, on javascript, this:

```
let select_token_input = document.getElementById('id_select_token');
                select_token_input.selectedIndex = 0;
```

But this also doesn't work, is angular overriding it?, how could I best achieve this?

Comment: You have tagged Angular and your title says Angular, but that is AngularJS code?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to angular and I thought this project was on Angular 2, but perhaps it wasn't, I updated it now.